# Using Bootstrap with Webpack

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I have an app that uses Webpack. I'm new to Webpack and trying to learn how to use it effectively. Specifically, I'm trying to import Bootstrap with Font Awesome into my project. I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659737/load-bootstrap-with-webpack-for-vue), however, I am still unable to use Bootstrap. I'm not sure if it's out-of-date, or if I'm misunderstanding something.

I tried loading Bootstrap and Font Awesome via the url-loader. I was referencing the following URLs:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

I also tried using loading Bootstrap and Font Awesome via NPM and then referencing it in my entry file like this:

```
require('bootstrap');
require('font-awesome');
```

It seems like this should be part of a commonly used template. However, I'm not finding one. How do I use Bootstrap and Font Awesome with Webpack?

However, I've come up short with that approach as well.

Comment: Why don't it work ``require('bootstrap'); require('font-awesome');`` in entry file? Do you have any errors? Can you add webpack config file?

Comment: @StanislavMayorov When I do `require('bootstrap');` the bootstrap CSS simply does not load. I installed bootstrap using `npm install bootstrap --save-dev`. I can see `bootstrap` in the `node_modules` directory. I can successfully run `webpack` from the command-line with `require('bootstrap')` in my entry-file. However, the CSS simply is not loaded when I visit the web page.

Comment: You must add loaders for css and fonts in your config. And don't forget  to import jquery because it needs for bootstrap.

Comment: @StanislavMayorov I have `css-loader` and `url-loader` in my config file. However,  I do not see any font-specific loaders listed in the loaders: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/.

Comment: Have you tried installing the npm packages for bootstrap and font awesome?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-webpack https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome-webpack That will put the files into `node_modules` and you should be able to import or require them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have created a simple example on [GitHub](https://github.com/StanislavMayorov/webpack2-bootstrap-example). Webpack 2 and Bootstrap 3 are used.

Install dependency `npm install jquery bootstrap`

**index.js**

```
require('bootstrap');
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
require('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'); //Optional. The question author uses this package.
```

**webpack**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "index.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [    
            {
                test: /\.woff2?$|\.ttf$|\.eot$|\.svg$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "file-loader"
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader'
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.styles.css'),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            // inject ES5 modules as global vars
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ]
};
```

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/bundle.styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

You can use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` if don't want to insert `bundle.styles.css` and `bundle.js` manually.

Comment: why not load less instead of css?

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev Because it will increase build time. Author didn't want to use bootstrap variables.
You can use less and add `less-loader` if you need it.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 **does not** need tether.js. That's a Bootstrap 4 requirement.

Answer (score 1):

if you are not generating your base HTML file dynamically then you can symply include a `<link>` tag in your base html's head section (means same base html file everywhere)

and if you want to use it using webpack then along with url-loader you need to use either `style-loader` and `css-loader` (if you want to insert the style as `style` tag in head witch is probabbly not the case)

or you can use webpack's `extract to text` plugin to load as a different file and insert it using html `link` tag

for reference you can use this open source project's configration file

[webpack production config](https://github.com/andrewngu/sound-redux/blob/master/client/webpack.prod.config.js)

and

[webpack developement config](https://github.com/andrewngu/sound-redux/blob/master/client/webpack.dev.config.js)

edit: link update

Comment: The links are dead